# converting vowels in a list to uppercase

Tags: c#

I have a char list of which I want to convert the vowels of this list to uppercase.

With the way I am doing it only returns the vowels and excludes all the consonants.

I know this is very elementary but how would I do this correctly.?

```
List<char> lstVowels = new List<char>() {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

lstChar = lstChar.Where(p=>lstVowels.Contains(p)).Select(t => char.ToUpper(t)).ToList();
//lstChar contains a set of consonants and vowels
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a character exists in `lstVowels` then convert it to uppercase; otherwise, just keep it as-is.

```
lstChar =
    lstChar.Select(c => lstVowels.Contains(c) ? char.ToUpper(c) : c).ToList();
```

In your code, the `Where` clause causes you to lose all characters that don't exist in `lstVowels`.

Answer (score 3):

personally I'd include an ternary if into your select instead

```
lstChar.Select(c => lstVowels.Contains(c) ? char.ToUpper(c) : c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are filtering out consonants instead of just keeping them unchanged.

```
 lstChar.Select(c => lstVowels.Contains(c) ? Char.ToUpper(c) : c)
```